# What does this mean in angular, what kind of type is this?

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to know what this type means:

```
type newtype = (state: EntityState<IEntities>) => IEntities[];
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Angular, this is just a typescript function type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EntityState<T>` is an ngrx type, you could [check here.](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/interfaces)

And `type newtype = (state: EntityState<IEntities>) => IEntities[];` defines a function type that recieves a state parameter of type `EntityState<IEntities>` and returns an `IEntities[]` array.